# Keras custom loss for transfer learning- update values inside loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I am trying to implement a custom loss function where I change the value of y_true and y_pred based on the value of y_true. Wherever y_true == 10**6 I want to change the value of y_true and y_pred to be 0 (so the contribution to the binary cross entropy loss is 0). My code is as follows

```
def custom_loss_match(y_true, y_pred):
  '''custom loss to set y_true == y_pred wherever
  y_true == 10**6 (meaning true match status is unknown)
  this way we ignore the loss where match status is unknown'''

  bool_mask = tf.equal(y_true, 10**6)
  indices = tf.where(bool_mask)
  if len(indices) != 0:
    y_true = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(y_true, indices, tf.cast([0]*len(indices), tf.int64))
    y_pred = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(y_pred, indices, tf.cast([0]*len(indices), tf.float32))

  return keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)(y_true, y_pred)
```

The loss function seems to work as intended when I create my own toy y_true and y_pred. For example the following code returns something reasonable.

```
custom_loss_match(tf.constant([[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[10**6]], dtype=tf.int64), 
                  np.array([[np.random.random()] for _ in range(8)]))
```

However when I train I get an error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Indices and updates specified for empty output shape
     [[{{node custom_loss_match/cond/then/_0/custom_loss_match/cond/TensorScatterUpdate}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_326910]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I am fairly certain that it has something to do with the tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update() line but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any insight is greatly appreciated.
Also in case anyone is wondering why I would want to do something like this, I'm trying to use transfer learning with a gradient reversal layer. So I am training with two loss functions. For one of the loss function I don't have labels for some of the data points. So for the unlabeled data I'm putting labels in as 10**6 and trying to implement the custom loss function to ignore these unlabeled data points. Basically trying to follow [this](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/ganin15.pdf) paper. Also if anyone has a better idea about how to implement this idea I'm definitely open to it. Thanks!

**EDIT**

In case anyone is reading this later I think I found a solution.

```
def custom_loss_match(y_true, y_pred):
  '''custom loss to set y_true == y_pred where ever
  y_true == 10**6 (meaning true match status is unknown)
  this way we ignore the loss where match status is unknown'''

  bool_mask = tf.not_equal(y_true, 10**6)

  y_true *= tf.cast(bool_mask, dtype=tf.int64)
  y_pred *= tf.cast(bool_mask, dtype=tf.float32)

  return keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)(y_true, y_pred)
```